# Saturated absorption spectroscopy

Tags: spectroscopy

During the Doppler-free Rb saturation spectroscopy experiment we have the spectrum shift to the left on the frequency axis with increasing current or the temperature. I would appreciate it if anyone can shortly explain why.

Comment: Adding some detail or a reference might be helpful. Shift in which spectrum? Are you talking about doppler-broadening?

Comment: Rb-spectrum is shifting its position, but it is doppler-free spectroscopy, can there still be doppler broadening in it?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what ref or plot you're looking at, but in doppler-free spectroscopy you can remove enough of the doppler-broadening to resolve peaks from hyperfine energy levels (e.g. in Rb), but the broadening due to thermal motion still smears out the peaks quite a bit